# Problem 106C from CF doesn't work properly

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

Question : https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/106/C

> Lavrenty, a baker, is going to make several buns with stuffings and
>   sell them.
>
> Lavrenty has n grams of dough as well as m different stuffing types.
>   The stuffing types are numerated from 1 to m. Lavrenty knows that he
>   has ai grams left of the i-th stuffing. It takes exactly bi grams of
>   stuffing i and ci grams of dough to cook a bun with the i-th stuffing.
>   Such bun can be sold for di tugriks.
>
> Also he can make buns without stuffings. Each of such buns requires c0
>   grams of dough and it can be sold for d0 tugriks. So Lavrenty can cook
>   any number of buns with different stuffings or without it unless he
>   runs out of dough and the stuffings. Lavrenty throws away all excess
>   material left after baking.
>
> Find the maximum number of tugriks Lavrenty can earn.

Here's my algorithm which is written in a self-explanatory manner. I think it is correct and the code is corrupted.

```
/*
dp[amt-of-dough-used_i][stuffing-used_j][stuffing_times-used_k] = max profit when i grams of dough is used for making stuffing j for a total of k times.


dp[i][j][k]=dp[i-k*c[i]][j][0] for all k=0,1,...,b[i]/c[i].

best[amt-of-dough-used_i] = max(dp[i][j][k] for all j,k).

Answer :

max(best[i] + d*[(n-i)/c] for all i)
*/
```

Here's my code :
https://ideone.com/70FMql

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n,m,c_0,d_0;
    cin>>n>>m>>c_0>>d_0;
    int dp[n+1][m+1][101];
    int a[m+1], b[m+1], c[m+1], d[m+1];
    for (int i=1; i<=m; m++)
        cin>>a[i]>>b[i]>>c[i]>>d[i];


    for (int i=0; i<=n; i++)
    for (int j=1; j<=m; j++)
    for (int k=0; k<=a[j]/b[j]; k++)
    {
        dp[i][j][0]=d[j];

        if (k!=0) dp[i][j][k]=0;

    }

    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
        for (int j=1; j<=m; j++)
            for (int k=0; k<=a[j]/b[j]; k++)

                if (i>=k*c[i])
                dp[i][j][k]=dp[i-k*c[i]][j][0];

    int best[n+1];
    for (int i=0; i<=n; i++) best[i]=0;
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
        for (int j=1; j<=m; j++)
        for (int k=0; k<=a[j]/b[j]; k++)
            best[i]=max(best[i],dp[i][j][k]);

    int ans=0;
    for (int i=0; i<=n; i++)
        ans = max(ans, best[i] + d_0*(n-i)/c_0);

    cout<<ans<<endl;
}
```

**2 Sample Test Cases have been provided in the Ideone link mentioned.

Comment: My questions have been flagged previously for asking competitive programming questions as they are considered off-topic here. In that regard, please have a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298212/where-to-ask-competitive-programming-related-problems-actually as I have tried to follow the first answer. Please ignore if this statement was unnecessary.

Comment: I agree more with the second answer from meta: it's the question format which makes it on-topic. SO is generally not for "debug my code for me" questions, it's about some small specific problems you encounter with specific isolated behavior. In particular, you do not specify why exactly your code is incorrect. Does it crash on sample test cases? Does it crash on some other test you have? Does it get some non-Accepted outcome in the system?

Comment: @yeputons It's getting a TLE first of all and secondly, as a result of TLE, I can't verify if the algorithm works or not. And yes I tried to comply with the StackOverflow standards though I am not sure if I could. Please have a look and help.

Comment: Bumping the question, please have a look. I have tried my best to comply with the Stack Overflow standards.

Comment: Your algorithm is wrong. How does it take into account the possibility of baking multiple types of bread?